# Spring Cloud Config: NoSuchLabelException

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have a simple Spring Config Server application which consumes the configuration data from a GIT repository. This Config Server works perfectly as expected in my local and development environment. Once deployed to the production server though, I kept seeing this error: org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NoSuchLabelException: No such label: master

Here is the whole JSON return:

```
{
  "status": "DOWN",
  "configServer": {
    "status": "DOWN",
    "repository": {
      "application": "app",
      "profiles": "default"
    },
    "error": "org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NoSuchLabelException: No such label: master"
  },
  "discoveryComposite": {
    "description": "Discovery Client not initialized",
    "status": "UNKNOWN",
    "discoveryClient": {
      "description": "Discovery Client not initialized",
      "status": "UNKNOWN"
    }
  },
  "diskSpace": {
    "status": "UP",
    "total": 10434699264,
    "free": 6599856128,
    "threshold": 10485760
  },
  "refreshScope": {
    "status": "UP"
  },
  "hystrix": {
    "status": "UP"
  }
}
```

So I traced it down to the spring-cloud-config GitHub repo, and saw that it is being thrown here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/b7afa2bb641913b89e32ae258bd6ec442080b9e6/spring-cloud-config-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/server/environment/JGitEnvironmentRepository.java#185  This error is thrown by GitCommand class's call() method on line 235 when a Git branch is not found. But I can't for the life of me understand why!!! I have double-checked and verified that the "master" branch does indeed exist in the GIT repository for configuration properties.

The application properties for the Config Server are defined in a bootstrap.yml file, as follows:

```
server:
  port: 8080

management:
  context-path: /admin

endpoints:
  enabled:  false
  health:
    enabled: true

logging:
  level:
    com.netflix.discovery: 'OFF'
    org.springframework.cloud: 'DEBUG'

eureka:
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
    statusPageUrlPath: /admin/info
    healthCheckUrlPath: /admin/health

spring:
  application:
    name: config-service
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
      failFast: true
      server:
        git:
          uri: 'https://some-spring-config-repo.git'
          username: 'fakeuser'
          password: 'fakepass'
          basedir: "${catalina.home}/target/config"`
```

Any help would be most appreciated!!

Comment: Could you post config server's application properties?

Comment: Hi @nurgasemetey, my application properties are defined in a bootstrap.yml file. Its content is apparently too long to be posted in the comment section, so I edited my original post and included it there. Thank you for responding! :)

Comment: Can you verify that `http://<configserverhost>:<port>/app/default` works?

Comment: Is there any security on config server?

Comment: @spencergibb So sorry about the late response!! The `http://<configserverhost>:<port>/app/default` works for the DEV server, but still not the prod server. There is no security on the config server. I suspected it might fail for whatever reason connecting to the GIT Repo, so now I am having it point at this: https://github.com/txiasummer/txia-config-repo.git  Again, works on DEV server, but not PROD. :(

Comment: @spencergibb when I hit `http://<configserverhost>:<port>/app/default` on the PROD server, the error I get says: `{
  "timestamp": 1474402151210,
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "exception": "org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NoSuchLabelException",
  "message": "No such label: master",
  "path": "/config-server/app/default"
}`

Comment: @QingXia did you solve this problem? I faced same problem :/

Answer (score 1):

Posting this in case someone else finds this uselful
I'm using the below setting in the properties file of the config server to indicate the "main" branch
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main

Additional info - my git repo is not public , I'm using the new personal access token based authentication instead of the older username/password authentication